# How to Get / Set Div and Table Width / Height

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Table (or a region) and want to set it's Width and Height value to another Div (or region).

The second one is actually a Ajax Indicator modal which display a loading text when the page is asynchronously post back. here is the example

```
<table id="MainTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
             Content ....
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="Progress">
     Ajax Indocator
</div>
```

the following javascript didn't work

```
document.getElementById("Progress").style.width = document.getElementById("MainTable").style.width;
document.getElementById("Progress").style.height = document.getElementById("MainTable").style.height;
```

It should work both on IE and FireFox. how to correct it.

I checked some other solution in StackOverFlow but I couldn't fix it.

I'm waiting to hear from you.

---

Update : I use this

```
<script>
function SetSize(regionToChange, mainRegion) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#regionToChange)
 .width($('#mainRegion).outerWidth())
 .height($('#mainRegion).outerHeight());
    }); 
}
</script>
```

and I call it like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" SkinID="Button" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_OnClick" OnClientClick="SetSize('Progress', 'MainTable');" />
```

But it shows me an error which can not find the object

---

**Update 2** I see this error

[image]

and in debugger I face with this

[image]

Comment: it looks like you are short of single-quotes. Are those parameters string literals or DOM elements?

Comment: The `regionToChange` is always a `DIV` element and `mainregion` is always a `Table` or a `fieldset` or a `Div` and as you can see in my question I call the `SetSize` method with 2 parameters. One for Div to change and One for specifing an object to use width and height propertis values.. So This method is Common and use for all pages so it has to get 2 parameters and shouldn't be static.

Comment: understood, but that doesn't answer my question. If the parameters are DOM objects use `$(regionToChange)`. If they are string literals use `$('#' + regionToChange)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jQuery you can do

```
$("#Progress").css('width', function(){
   return $("#MainTable").width()+'px';
});
```

and so with the height...

**edit**

on javascript,

this

```
document.getElementById("Progress").style.width = document.getElementById("MainTable").style.width;
document.getElementById("Progress").style.height = document.getElementById("MainTable").style.height;
```

will work if your html is something like this for id="MainTable"

```
<table id="MainTable" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
             Content ....
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

because you are accessing style attribute...

**edit2**

```
 function SetSize(regionToChange, mainRegion) {
        $(regionToChange)
         .width($(mainRegion).outerWidth())
         .height($(mainRegion).outerHeight());

  }

//you can use it as

SetSize('#Progress','#MainTable'); // prefix '#'if it's an ID
```

Comment: @Reigel - what about Javascript?

Comment: @Reigel - I used yours and it doesn't worked. I also update my question with query you mentioned but it shows an error. and it doesn't work.  take a look please.

Comment: note that you must include http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js before using that...

Comment: @Reigel - I've added Jquery `1.4.2 min` to my project and I face with the bug I mentioned in `Update 2`. you can see it in my question. Thank you in advance

Comment: did you prefix a `#` and not something like this `OnClientClick="SetSize('Progress', 'MainTable');"` ?

Comment: @jAndy hehe... he used your answer wrongly and ask me how to correct it.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

spoken in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#Progress')
     .width($('#MainTable').outerWidth())
     .height($('#MainTable').outerHeight());
});
```

Comment: What about Javascript - And notethat this is a common method which will use in all pages of application so the IDs should be variable.

Comment: Well, actually it IS javascript. If you are looking for cross-browser compatibility using a framework like jQuery is the best thing you can do.